# My program is outputting the wrong values

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a enigma machine and im having trouble with the first rotor all the other roter work apart from this one. I am not getting the right results

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] Alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
    char[] rout1 = "JGDQOXUSCAMIFRVTPNEWKBLZYH".ToCharArray();

    char l1;

    Console.Write("Enter a character -- ");
    Char Letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(Letter);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (Letter == rout1[i])
        {
            l1 = Alpha[i];
            Console.WriteLine(l1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

A to be J, B to be G, C to be D, D to be Q.
However A is J, B is V, C is I D is C ,E IS S

Comment: Hint: you're checking whether the input matches an element in `rout1`, and then using the corresponding element in `Alpha`. I suspect you want that to be the other way round...

Comment: Please provide an input and an output that is wrong (unless you want it the other way around as suggested)

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you checked the values that you are comparing???  It's very clear that you're comparing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF  A to be J, B to be G, C to be D, D to be Q you need to change the condition

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] Alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
    char[] rout1 = "JGDQOXUSCAMIFRVTPNEWKBLZYH".ToCharArray();

    char l1;

    Console.Write("Enter a character -- ");
    Char Letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(Letter);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (Letter == Alpha[i])
        {
            l1 = rout1[i];
            Console.WriteLine(l1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to check against `Alpha` and not againts `rout1`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: please, if you don't have anymore doubts, you can mark this answer as correct.